# connection refused when I'm transfering data from Dell laptop to Lenovo laptop

Tags: 12.04

I don't have a external hard disk because of that I'm trying to transfer data from Dell laptop to Lenovo through `scp`, and its showing:

```
ssh: connect to host 169.144.38.162 port 1807: Connection refused
```

and for the next time its showing:

```
ssh: connect to host 169.144.38.162 port 1807: Connection timed out,
```

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: Please show the command line you use.

Comment: Have you used the `-v` flag? If not, try it and post the output.

Comment: Also look in `/var/log/auth.log` for messages of sshd on the remote machine.

Comment: Please show the result of `ssh 169.144.38.162` and `ssh -p 1807 169.44.38.162`. Also please confirm that you have explicitly configured `sshd` on the remote machine to listen on port 1807 (instead of the standard 22).